# Accessing child fields of a nested json data using sparksql

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm doing an exploratory data analysis with hadoop job history files log data.
Below given is the sample data used for the analysis

```
{"type":"AM_STARTED","event":{"org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.AMStarted":{"applicationAttemptId":"appattempt_1450790831122_0001_000001","startTime":1450791753482,"containerId":"container_1450790831122_0001_01_000001","nodeManagerHost":"centos65","nodeManagerPort":52981,"nodeManagerHttpPort":8042}}}
```

i just need to select the child values like applicationAttemptId, startTime, containerId  of the event

> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.AMStarted

i tried the below simple select query

```
val out=sqlcontext.sql("select event.org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.AMStarted.applicationAttemptId from sample")
```

but it throws the below error

> org.apache.spark.sql.analysisException: no such struct field org in org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.AMStarted.applicationAttemptId

unfortunately the data field look like this "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.AMStarted"

i manipulated the data myself like this org_apache_hadoop_mapreduce_jobhistory.AMStarted and tried the same query like this one below

```
val out=sqlcontext.sql("select event.org_apache_hadoop_mapreduce_jobhistory_AMStarted.applicationAttemptId from sample")
```

Now i'm able to access the child fields of AMStarted. but it's not the right way to do so,
Is there any way to do so without manipulating the data.

Answer (score 1):

After spending some quality time searching for a solution , got the simple idea of using back ticks as quotes in the field name did the trick for me.

```
`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory`.AMStarted
```

And then the query works like a charm,

```
val out=sqlcontext.sql("select event.`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.AMStarted'.applicationAttemptId from sample")
```